# Which graphic card for multiple monitors on linux without xinerama?

Tags: linux, graphics-card, multiple-monitors, linux-mint, nvidia-graphics-card

I have a 3 24" monitors, setup with 2 in portrait mode and 1 horizontal ( |-| ) connected to 2 NVIDIA Quadro FX 580 and I'm running Mint 17 Qiana 64 bit (Cinnamon 2.2.13).

The configuration works but, because of Xinerama, I don't have composite and Cinnamon runs in fallback mode. This is a problem because the current version of Chrome suffers and I have to run it with the "-disable-gpu" option. Also, I don't play games (I use my workstation just for work) but performances aren't brilliant when I have many windows open.

I want to fix this problem and I've heard that Kepler based cards can run multiple monitors, can have hardware acceleration enabled and this removes the need of Xinerama and, consequently, all the issues I'm experimenting.

Knowing that I can't change my current monitors layout, I'd like to know:

- Is it true that with a Kepler based cards can run multiple monitors without xinerama?
- If I purchase a Kepler based card can I finally have a fully working Cinnamon? (no fallback with xrandr)
- Does anybody have any suggestion/experience with such a configuration? (I'm not stuck with Kepler but I'd rather prefer NVIDIA over ATI)

Some futher information:

Also, my monitors are currently connected using the display ports (eventually I can change the cables but if I can avoid that I'd be happy)

- I've seen the NVS 510 which has 4 display ports but it looks a little bit weak to me (but I don't understand that much about graphic cards)

Comment: Shopping recommendations are off topic and so I have removed that part from your question.  Your other questions appear fine but please do not ask us to recommend you a product. See [Q&A is Hard, Let’s Go Shopping!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Comment: I'm sorry about that. I genuinely gave that information to better address the readers.

Comment: what a pity. This was such a cool question ...